# How can I install Visual Studio to a removable drive?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My internal SSD is too small to hold Visual Studio, but the installer doesn't let me install VS into my removable drive.

Is there any way (or trick) to install it?

Comment: Did you find [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e7160ef-505e-4c48-a1aa-78e778c13ee0/install-visual-studio-2017-in-d-drive?forum=vssetup) in your searches? If it doesn't apply, perhaps state why (e.g. earlier version of VS, or you tried it and it "did not work" but by specific on *how* it failed to work as you expected)

Comment: That post doesn't apply, sorry. For me, when I select the removable drive location it says: "Invalid location". I will post an image ASAP.

Comment: Cannot say for sure but a lot of Visual Studio seems to still rely upon COM registrations, which relies on the registry and some funky usages of the registry to boot ([Experimental Hive/Instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx) anyone?). So since it's really not going to be portable in any meaningful way, they may prevent it.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't design VS in a way to be installed on a removal drive, not even a secondary drive. Many components/dependencies must be there on the system drive. Thus, this question has no answer, unless one day Microsoft changes its mind. Upgrade your machine and there would be no such issue, or use a lite editor like VSCode.

Answer (score 5):

Very late to the problem, but leaving a comment in case anybody else is still stuck.

My laptop also has a very small internal SSD, and a much larger micro SD card, which lives permanently in the card reader.

I was able to use a symbolic link give Visual Studio the illusion that it is installing on the internal SSD, when the files are actually located on removable media. Naturally, read/write performance will suffer, but at least I can install Visual Studio without completely filling my system disk.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink

From cmd (not powershell):

```
mklink /d "C:\Visual Studio\" "<removable drive letter>\Visual Studio\"
```

Comment: Run cmd.exe as administrator before running the mklink command